# How to make Pandas Dataframe to understand and evaluate some expressions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

Suppose I have a column like this-

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b':[10,20,30], 'c':[8,9,10]}) 
here columns are -
c = ['a','b','c']
I can calculate different formulas like this -
df['sum'] = df[c].sum(axis=1)
df['avg'] = df[c].mean(axis=1)
```

Now I have a file where the formulas are written in below formats-

```
1. SUM(df[c])
2. AVG(df[c]) + MAX(df[c])
3. AVG(SUM(df[c])) * 100
etc..
Now is it possible to make above expressions being calculated by pandas without  writing much logics in python code?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b':[10,20,30], 'c':[8,9,10]})

def SUM(dfcols):
    return np.sum(dfcols)

SUM(df['a'])

np.average(df['a'])
np.amax(df['a'])
```

With these you can do all you need.